# Discord.js - Bot erroring when trying to add a role to a new member

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am enclosing here the code I wrote that should automatically grant a roll to any new user who logs into my server (I have a roll named member) and attach a link to the error message that appears to me, I would love if someone could help me.

This is the link of the error:  https://prnt.sc/109bik1

And this is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member)  => { 
  let welcomeRole = member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');
  member.roles.add(welcomeRole);
})

client.login(/*Here is the TOKEN*/);
```

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions. You have received the answer to this issue on your previous question.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not receive an answer
And now I was able to improve the code but I have an error
Believe it will be easier for me to answer when they see the error

Comment: You're trying to find the role in the member, not the guild. change member.guild.roles.cache to guild.roles.cache

Comment: Really thank you indeed this was the solution

Comment: Indeed it works for me when the roll is in English as in the "member" example but it does not work for me in a foreign language, is there a way to make the code if ID? So that I do not change in which language I wrote the roll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are checking the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)'s role collection when they join, which most likely is empty, not the server's.

---

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member)  => { 
  let welcomeRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');
  if (!welcomeRole) return console.log('Couldn\'t find the member role.');
  member.roles.add(welcomeRole);
})

client.login(/*Here is the TOKEN*/);
```

Comment: Really thank you indeed this was the solution

Comment: Indeed it works for me when the roll is in English as in the "member" example but it does not work for me in a foreign language, is there a way to make the code if ID? So that I do not change in which language I wrote the roll?

Comment: You can get the role by id using: `member.guild.roles.cache.get("ROLEID");`

Comment: I do not have your option working for some reason, I attach the error in the first link, and my code in the second photo, I would love if you could help me understand where the problem is
Code error: https://prnt.sc/109ith9,   The code itself: https://prnt.sc/109ivr7

Comment: I would be very happy if you could make a code that works this way that you would write it as an answer to my question and not in the comments.
As you rewrote the code above. Thank you very much

Comment: Make sure your bot has permission to add roles.

Comment: He has administrator privileges